# Can angular be exposed as webservice API?

Tags: angular, typescript, web-services

I want to expose angular as web service, is that possible?
In other words, can a backend calls angular, using typescript language?

Answer (score 0):

NO, it's not possible. Angular is a FRONT-END framework

Answer (score -1):

Strictly speaking, It is not recommended but I would say it is possible.

Basically, everyone will say that it is just "FrontEnd" web framwork.
But I see that it also can be a multi-platform framework for frontend and  backend as well. The main Angular core team didn't define this framework as one "Frontend" framework. Rather, it says one framework across all platform. It means it can be transformed anything. They think bigger than  non-angular developers. I see the bigger picture and future with Angular. Of course, this is just mainly used for the mobile and desktop for now. Many developers have a skeptical idea of this. I would agree.

For example, Ionic/Nativescript. They adopted Angular as a core framework. Yes, this is for mobile(Frontend right?).

However, What about **Nest.js**. Cool right?
This is totally server-side web framework for "Backend".
The fact is that this framework heavily referenced "Angular framework" such as **Angular-like Dependency Injection system**.
They even mentioned **"The architecture is heavily inspired by Angular."**

**Let's say you are a pioneer and you can make it possible.
I highly recommend to play with the Angular platform source codebase.**
Git clone and modify something and build it(it takes some time but it should work at your local computer). If you see the github codebase, this is huge and actually have capability or "potential" to serve as a backend.

Of course, it depends on a situation. So ask yourself What kind of your expectation from it and what the purpose is.

Angular is just javascript(transpiled by Typscript) program.
After having transpiled javascript static files, it requires a http server to serve the files.
Luckily, Angular Frmaework has its own local server( called **ng serve**  yes we know this one which is a cute http/https server.

Thus, technically speaking, Angular is "Framework" not library. Framework includes many tools and even app servers in it. I would say that it's possible and it can even directly communicate with other Angular applications with websocket and webRTC as well.
Don't make me wrong. Once again, It is only possible with the embedded Angular Serve module(**ng serve**) if you don't want to install other 3rd party http server.

These days, What a Javascript/Typescript world. Javascript/Typescript can do everything. Angular is a part of it and it is the most advanced web framework among others.

Check out the following github codes. Hope you like my answer. Take care.

[angular-cli/packages/angular_devkit/core/node/](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/tree/master/packages/angular_devkit/core/node)

[architect-command.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/angular/cli/models/architect-command.ts)

[angular devkit dev-server](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/tree/master/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/dev-server)

> *Anything is possible*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort!